# \captionof{figure} starts with number 2

Tags: numbering, subcaption

Why does the caption start with number 2 and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{Description}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Maybe also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327923/labeling-subcaption)

Comment: hy are you posting the same question twice? It is pretty much very very lickely that solving one mystery will automatically get rid of the other one.

Comment: Argh, now i voted on the wrong one to close.

Comment: I actually don't know if it's related. But I can produce both "errors" without the other

Comment: Unfortunately this question was already closed so I cannot answer. So I will do so within this comment: Just change `\captionof{figure}{...}` to `\caption{...}` and the counting will be fine. Background: With `\captionsetup{type=figure}` you say "Hey, here starts some kind of figure, so increase the figure counter etc.". And with `\captionof{figure}{...}` you say "Hey, this isn't a figure but typeset the caption like a figure caption and btw please increase the figure counter". So it gets incremented twice.

Comment: This bug (Is it one?) only appears when I use it with subfigures. Thanks. Actually I got a solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327933/110154), which uses minipages and solves my problem.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that question @Johannes_B? Really confused. A is a duplicate of B and B is a duplicate of C, but A and C seem very different, A and B seem somewhat different and B and C seem fairly different.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt So you use `\caption` even outside a float?

Comment: @cfr Yes. When using the caption package `\captionof{figure}{...}` is only a abbreviation of `\captionsetup{type=figure}\caption{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `H` placement of a figure environment, or add this as a workaround: `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Description}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{Description}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because I don't want that my images float

Comment: OK. Please see my updated answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I heard, that `H` actually doesn't mean here to 100%, so I'm still avoiding it. I got a solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327933/110154) which uses minipages, which solves this problem too

Comment: It really means here (as far as I know), but this implies a drawback: you may have unwanted whitespace if the image has to go to next page. In my opinion, it is wiser to let LaTeX decide first, and  in a second time use the `H` joker if you think it's not the right choice.

Comment: I definitely want the images to show up, where I place them