# Labeling subcaption

Tags: labels, subcaption

The reference to my sub caption doesn't work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption*{Text 0}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
\caption*{Text 1\label{here}}
\end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{Description}
\end{center}

Look at \Cref{here}.
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Maybe also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/captionoffigure-starts-with-number-2)

---

**UPDATE:**

It should produce `Look at Text 1`

Actually it's always the same text, so I would really like a solution where my counter is `0,1, ...` at the and of the caption.
Or (maybe to use with `\caption{\empty}` where my counter is `Text 0, Text 1, ...`

Comment: change into : `\caption{Text 1}\label{here}`

Comment: I do not want the counter (a). Actually the Number ab the end is my counter, so I also would like a solution, where the caption is overridden and `caption{Text}`would produce `Text #` where `#` is a number. In face also there is always the same text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since counters are reset to zero, you can't use `\refstepcounter` to set up the `\label`.  OTOH, you need `\refstepcounter` for cleverref and hyperref.  So I generate the label before `\refstepcounter` then reset `\@currentlabel` after.

I see that `\subcaption` defines skip=6pt, but I can't figure out where skip is used.  Also, `\caption` somehow knows whether it is at the top or bottom.  I had to set up `\mycaption` for bottom only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{subfig}[figure]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycaption}{\edef\@templabel{Text \thesubfig}%
  \refstepcounter{subfig}%
  \let\@currentlabel=\@templabel% \global?
  \vspace{6pt}%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\@currentlabel}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\topanchor}[1]% #1 = counter
  {\refstepcounter{#1}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}\par}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{center}
\topanchor{figure}%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\topanchor{subfig}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\mycaption
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\topanchor{subfig}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
\mycaption\label{here}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{Description}\label{there}
\end{center}

Look at \ref{here}.

Hyperlink test \ref{there}.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The `\captionsetup{type=figure}` should come after `\begin{center}`

Comment: This also solved my problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/captionoffigure-starts-with-number-2/327925?noredirect=1#comment802794_327925)

Comment: This solution adds more whitespace between the image and the caption. Is that fixable?

Comment: Actually, the \captionsetup is not needed with minipages.  I'll check \subcaption to see what gaps it uses.

Comment: I need the `\captionsetup` for telling `hyperref` where to jump (not included in MWE)

Comment: (your placement of `\captionsetup` causes a crash)

Comment: For hyperref I need to make some changes.

Comment: Are you sure? I also use `cleveref` (includes after `hyperref`)

Comment: `\captionsetup{type=figure}` within the main body of the document? Please don't try this at home. (And never do this in an answer on SX.)

Comment: Is there anything else which needs to be fixed?

Comment: What are you asking by `\global?`? (The whitespace now is smaller that the original one, but I'm fine with how it is)

Comment: `\topanchor{figure}%` causes the warning `Package caption Warning: The option 'hypcap=true' will be ignored for this`, so I'm just going to use `\captionsetup{type=figure}`

Comment: BTW, with \captionsetup{type=figure} you can use \caption instead of \captionof{figure}.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the package `nameref` for this. It will find the captiontext for you.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

  \section{Section}
  \begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
      \caption{Text 1}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace{\columnsep}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
      \caption{Text 2}\label{fig:here}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Description}
  \end{figure}

  Look at ``\nameref{fig:here}''.
\end{document}
```