# How to define subfigure in a .cls (class) of latex project?

Tags: subfloats, subfiles

For my thesis work, I have a template given by my university which has a class(.cls), many sections(.tex) and a bibliography(.bib) in separate files. In the thesisclass.cls file everything has been defined and has been called in main.tex file as a `\documentclass{thesisclass}.`

Now the problem is, there is no provision given for sub captioning in thesisclass.cls. therefore I can not make a sub figure and captions as we see many of the tutorials. Could anobody help me to define subfigure and captioning in thesisclass.cls file?

If anybody wants to see my entire thesis files(without the contents), I can make available.

For now you can see my thesisclass.cls as below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}                                        % We do need LaTeX2e
\ProvidesClass{thesisclass}
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrbook} % Class based on scrbook

%% Packages
%%---------
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}%, english
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=true, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[raiselinks = true, bookmarks = true, bookmarksopenlevel = 1, bookmarksopen=true, hyperindex = true, plainpages  = false, pdfpagelabels = true, pdfborder = {0.5}, colorlinks = true,  linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%% New commands
%%-------------

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\chapterheadfont}{}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

%% Globalsetting
%%--------------
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmarginsrb{3cm}{1cm}{3cm}{1cm}{6mm}{7mm}{5mm}{15mm}

\parindent 0cm
\parskip1.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex
\changefont{phv}{m}{n}

\onehalfspacing

%% Headings
%%---------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\headfont\nouppercase{\rightmark}}   % Header for left page (odd)
\fancyhead[RE]{\headfont\nouppercase{\leftmark}}    % Header for right page (even)
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}                                          % No Header and Footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

%% Style of Captions
%%------------------
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
{\chapterheadstartvskip}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@startsection{section}%
{1}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}            % Pre-Margin
{0.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}      % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\Large\bfseries}   % Style
%
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
\@startsection{subsection}%
{2}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{1.5ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}        % Pre-Margin
{0.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}      % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\large\bfseries}   % Style
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
\@startsection{subsubsection}%
{3}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{1.5ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}            % Pre-Margin
{0.2ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex}          % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\normalsize\bfseries}  % Style
}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
\@startsection{paragraph}%
{4}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{1.3ex plus 1ex minus 0.3ex}            % Pre-Margin
{0.2ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex}          % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\normalsize\bfseries}  % Style
}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
\@startsection{subparagraph}%
{5}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{1ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}              % Pre-Margin
{0.1ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}          % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\normalsize\bfseries}  % Style
}




%%  Style of chapter captions  
%% ---------------------------------
\newlength{\chapnolen}
\newlength{\chapparlen}
\newsavebox{\chapno}
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{0.2\textheight}
  \vskip -70\p@
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \savebox{\chapno}{\chapterheadfont\huge\bfseries \thechapter.}
        \settowidth{\chapnolen}{\usebox{\chapno}}
        \parbox[t]{\chapnolen}{\usebox{\chapno}}\nobreak\leavevmode
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@MM
    \setlength{\chapparlen}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\chapparlen}{-1.0\chapnolen}
    \addtolength{\chapparlen}{-2ex}
    \leavevmode\nobreak
    \parbox[t]{\chapparlen}{\raggedright\chapterheadfont\huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \chapterheadfont \huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

%% Style of content directory   
%% ---------------------------------
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{\contentsname}\chapterheadfont\oldtableofcontents}}
\let\@olddottedtocline\@dottedtocline
\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{\@olddottedtocline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\chapterheadfont #5}}


%%  Style of appendix numbering  
%% ----------------------------------
 \renewcommand\appendix{\par 
   \setcounter{section}{0}% 
   \setcounter{subsection}{0}% 
   \setcounter{figure}{0}%
   \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}% 
   \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}} 
   \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}}


%%  Abstract 
%% -----------------------------

\newcommand{\abstract}[1][\abstractname]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1][\abstractname]{\chapter*{#1}} 

\def\ackname{Acknowledgments}
\def\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\switcht@deutsch{\svlanginfo}
\def\switcht@english{\svlanginfo
    \def\abstractname{Abstract}
}
```

there is also definition for bibliogray, but that's not relavent here.

Comment: is use of package `subcaption` not sufficient? btw, it is sufficient to load it only ones ..., `subfigure` is obsolete, `hyperref` should be last in the preamble ...

Comment: @Zarko usage of subcaption package is not working! I tried many times.

Comment: hyperref should be last in the preamble . What do you mean by this? @Zarko

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327923/labeling-subcaption/327933?s=3|19.2147#327933 for example.

Comment: Welcome, you should complain to the univerity/maintainer for not choosing a proper name, for not having liense and copyright notes in the file and for loading obsolete packages. I cannot recommed using that clas. Apart from that, you hould read an introduction. Trying to mes with the class is a very bad start.

Comment: yes... i solved the problem.. remove 'subfigure' was the solution. thanks for supporting!

Comment: @jackyone Please turn your comment as an answer, so that we can vote it up and not have it as an unanswered question.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. Removing `subfigure` was the solution. Thanks for supporting in comments.