# Cannot use subfigure in l4dc2023 template

Tags: subcaption

I am using a conference latex template from https://l4dc.seas.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/l4dc_2023.zip but I cannot use `\subfigure` here. The minimal working example (by changing the `l4dc2023-sample.tex` file in the zip file) is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{l4dc2023}

% The following packages will be automatically loaded:
% amsmath, amssymb, natbib, graphicx, url, algorithm2e

\title[Short Title]{Full Title of Article}
\usepackage{times}

% Authors with different addresses:
\author{%
 \Name{Author Name1} \Email{abc@sample.com}\\
 \addr Address 1
 \AND
 \Name{Author Name2} \Email{xyz@sample.com}\\
 \addr Address 2%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}%
 An abstract would go here.%
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}%
  List of keywords%
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EXAMPLE 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a} \hfill
\caption{Example A}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b} \hfill
\caption{Example B}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Two Examples Visualization}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{yourbibfile}

\end{document}
```

However, if you change `\documentclass[12pt]{l4dc2023}` to `\documentclass{article}`, comment out `\title[Short Title]{Full Title of Article}` and add `\usepackage{subcaption}`, it will just work. I still need to write under this template, so I wonder if there is any workaround. I cannot understand what they define in the style file and hope someone can also explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: if you neeed subcaption, why do you only add it when using `article` ?

Comment: I suspect that they don't wnat you messing with their captions.  You can use a minipage instead of subrigure.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327923/labeling-subcaption for creating a subcaption.

Answer (score 1):

The class is not compatible with `subcaption` and, via `jmlrutils.sty`, it defines its own `\subfigure` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{l4dc2023}

% The following packages will be automatically loaded:
% amsmath, amssymb, natbib, graphicx, url, algorithm2e

\title[Short Title]{Full Title of Article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% Authors with different addresses:
\author{%
 \Name{Author Name1} \Email{abc@sample.com}\\
 \addr Address 1
 \AND
 \Name{Author Name2} \Email{xyz@sample.com}\\
 \addr Address 2
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
An abstract would go here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
  List of keywords
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EXAMPLE 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\subfigure[Example A]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfigure[Example B]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\caption{Two Examples Visualization}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]