# \begin{subfigure} & \captionof: Main figure counter incremented twice per figure

Tags: captions, subcaption

## Problem statement

I like to use the `\begin{subfigure}` environment from `\usepackage{subcaption}` in combination with the `\captionof` command.

This works in principle, but it seems that the particular combination of macros, environments, and packages results in the **main figure counter being incremented *twice* per figure** (rather than just once).

**I am looking for a solution that retains the current combination of macros, environments, and packages.** In particular, I rely on the use of `\captionof` for printing captions in the page margins (which is not demonstrated in this MWE).

Therefore, hacks that retain the given combination of `\begin{subfigure}` and `\captionof{}` are preferred over more elegant solutions that require different macros, environments, and packages. (However, I certainly would also be interested in *pointers* towards such more elegant solutions.)

## Minimal (non-)working example (MWE)

Compile with single run of `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    Figure 1A
    \caption{Subfig caption 1A}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    Figure 1B
    \caption{Subfig caption 1B}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    Figure 1C
    \caption{Subfig caption 1C}
  \end{subfigure}
  \captionof{figure}{Should be figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    Figure 2A
    \caption{Subfig caption 2A}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    Figure 2B
    \caption{Subfig caption 2B}
  \end{subfigure}
  \captionof{figure}{Should be figure 2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: The `marginnote` package is not necessary to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Thanks, well spotted - that's a leftover from a previous version of the MWE - I'll remove it.

Comment: I might be naive, but if you just convert all `\caption` to `\subcaption` and `\captionof{...}` to `\caption` you get your desired output.

Comment: This is not a viable solution for me for reasons beyond this MWE - I actually rely on `\captionof` for printing captions in the page margins (which was not necessary to demonstrate for this MWE). Turning `\caption` into `\subcaption` is feasible in my context, but in itself does not solve the problem (I tried, for the record).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you are interested in hacks, you could just add `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before each `\captionof` (or patch that command). (I just want to remind you of the "outside" in "Sometimes you want to typeset a caption outside a floating environment, putting a figure within a non-floating minipage for instance. For this purpose the caption package offers the command
" in the `caption` manual.) See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/captionoffigure-starts-with-number-2) for more information.

Comment: And [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/captionoffigure-starts-with-number-2#comment802829_327921) is the comment by the author of the `caption` and `subcaption` packages...

Comment: I agree that this should probably be considered a duplicate. The `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` is a nice idea - I'll try it.

Comment: Why can't you use `\caption` within floats and `\captionof` outside? I don't understand the point.

Comment: @marmot How is that a duplicate? The problem here is the abuse of `\captionof`, isn't it?

Comment: @marmot That doesn't make the question a duplicate. And comments are ephemeral. They are designed to disappear. So marking a question as a duplicate on the basis of a comment on the target is really problematic, however high quality the comment may be.

Comment: @marmot This question uses `\captionof` inside a float which is not what it is designed for. The other question uses `\captionof` outside any float which is what it is designed for.

Comment: No, `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` is not a nice idea. It gives the subfigures the wrong main number, will lead to wrong LoF entries (if this is turned on), could lead to duplicate hyperref anchors, and last but not least this workaround will fail with the upcoming version 3.4 of the caption package. Please just change the `\captionof` to `\caption` and all will be fine.

Comment: Some background information: The (sub)caption package has to increase the figure counter at the subfigures. When using `\captionof` instead of `\caption` the caption package currently does not associates this caption with the subfigures, and therefore does not know it has already increased the counter, and therefore it will be increased a second time.