# Captionof and subcaptionbox: placing the caption below the figure, while numbering them correctly (solved)

Tags: labels, two-column, subcaption, capt-of

In my document I'm using two columns. However, this has made it a bit more complicated to make (complex) figures in the text.

The problem I've encountered is that using subcaptionboxes creates wrong references in the text. [In the files provided](https://we.tl/t-v1I6BQ3Ovp) I've given an example in figure 1.3 (referenced as figure 1.4).

I think I understand why it does this. The (label of the) subcaptionbox wants to attach itself to the last figure captioned. That is the previous figure, but a new figure environment has been created. So, Latex interpretes it as two figures. To avoid this, the caption and label of this figure should be before the subcaptionbox, but that also means the caption is above the figure.

Is there a way to force the caption to be at the bottom? Or to label the subcaptions with the later made caption of the entire figure environment?

Please let me know if anything is unclear. And my gratitude in advance.

Start of code:

```
\documentclass{tudelft-report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\hyphenpenalty=100000
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{array}p}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5em}

%%%%% Begin of document %%%%%

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Stack Exchange}
\begin{multicols}{2}
```

Packages in class:

```
%% Main packages in the document
\RequirePackage{amsmath}    % Mathematics
\RequirePackage{amssymb}    % Symbols
\RequirePackage{siunitx}    % Various functions, e.g. \num{}

\RequirePackage{tabularx}   % Additional functions to tables
\RequirePackage{booktabs}   % Adds more line functionality to tables
\RequirePackage{longtable}  % Lets tables break over page
\RequirePackage{multirow}   % Counterpart of multi columns
\RequirePackage{enumitem}   % Customise the list spacing

\RequirePackage{geometry}   % Document geometry
\RequirePackage{titlesec}   % Custom titles
\RequirePackage{titletoc}   % Custom table of contents
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}   % Custom header/footer
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Improved referencing/links

\RequirePackage{graphicx}   % Adding images
\RequirePackage{float}      % Additional float parameters
\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf,justification=centering,footnotesize]{caption} % Captions

\RequirePackage{subcaption} % Subfigures and subcaptions
\RequirePackage{xcolor}     % Using colours in documents
\RequirePackage{tikz}       % Create graphic elements

\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex,style=apa]{biblatex}   % Manages bibliography
\RequirePackage{datetime}   % Used in preface for monthname
\RequirePackage{microtype}  % Refinements towards typographical perfection
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % Add the lists to the table of contents
\RequirePackage{xspace}     % Ensures correct spacing after macros like \deg
```

Document:

```
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Stack Exchange}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[Random text] figure \ref{fig:furnplot}. [Random text]

\begin{figure}[H]
\captionof{figure}{figure 1.1} \label{fig:furnplot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = left,xlabel = x,ylabel = {y},xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
\addplot[domain=0.1:5.1,samples=100]{-x*(1-cosh(1/(2*x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

[More text] A visual representation of these equations can be seen in figure \ref{fig:secfor}.

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \parbox{\columnwidth}{%
    \captionof{figure}{figure 1.2}  \label{fig:secfor}
\subcaptionbox{fig 1 2 a \label{sfig:secfora}}[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,axis lines = left,xlabel = x, ylabel = y,xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1,ymax=0,y dir = reverse,max space between ticks=1000pt,try min ticks = 3]
\addplot[domain=-1.2:-0.6,samples=7,-latex]{1.05*(cosh(x/1.05)-cosh(2.4/(2*1.05))};
\addplot[domain=-0.6:1.2,samples=10, dotted]{1.05*(cosh(x/1.05)-cosh(2.4/(2*1.05))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\\
\subcaptionbox{fig 1 2 b \label{sfig:secforb}}[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%        q
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth,yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=top,axis y line=left,ylabel = y, xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,y dir = reverse]
\addplot[domain=-1.2:-0.6,samples=7]{0.34*sqrt(1+sinh(x/1.05)^2)};
\addplot[samples=7, domain=-1.2:-0.6, quiver={u={0},v={0.34*sqrt(1+sinh(x/1.05)^2)}},-latex](x,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
    }%
    \end{figure}

[more text] figure \ref{fig:triangle}. [more text] figure \ref{sfig:secfora}[text] figure \ref{sfig:trianglea}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \parbox{\columnwidth}{%
\subcaptionbox{fig 1 3 a \label{sfig:trianglea}}[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Latex-] (0,0) -- (-1,-1/2) node[pos=0.5, xshift = -0.8em,yshift=0.8em]{1};
\draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (1,-2) node[pos=0.5, right]{2};
\draw[dotted] (1,-2) -- (0,-2-1/2);
\draw[darkgray,-Latex] (0,0) -- (0,-2-1/2) node[pos=0.5, left]{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\\
\subcaptionbox{fig 1 3 b}[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[pos=0.5, above]{$1$};
\draw[-Latex] (4,0) -- (4,-2) node[pos=0.5, right]{\large $\frac{1}{2}$};
\draw[darkgray] (0,0) -- (4,-2) node[pos=0.5, below]{\large $\frac{1}{7}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
    }%
    \captionof{figure}{figure 1.3}  \label{fig:triangle}
    \end{figure}

[text] (see the dotted line in figure \ref{sfig:secfora}) [more text] See figure \ref{fig:positions}.

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \captionof{figure}{figure 1.4} \label{fig:positions}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{fig 1 4 b}[3.5cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0,0)--(0,3);
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)},dashed] (-0.7,0)--(-0.7,3);
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0,0.3)--(-0.7,0.3);
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0,1.1)--(-0.7,1.1);
\fill[rotate around={15:(0,0)},pattern=north east lines] (0,0.3) rectangle ++(-0.7,0.8);
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)},|-|] (-0.9,0.3)--(-0.9,1.1) node[pos=1, above]{t};
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)},|-|] (-1.3,0.3)--(-1.3,1.1) node[pos=1, above,xshift=-0.5em]{$h(s)$};
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0.2,0.3)--(0.3,0.3) node[pos=1.0, right]{$\sigma_0(s)$};
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0.2,1.1)--(0.3,1.1) node[pos=1.0, right]{$\sigma_1(s)$};
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0.2,1.9)--(0.3,1.9) node[pos=1.0, right]{$\sigma_2(s)$};
\draw[rotate around={15:(0,0)}] (0.2,2.3)--(0.3,2.3) node[pos=1.0, right]{$\tau_2(s)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
    \end{figure}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here: [\captionof{figure} starts with number 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/captionoffigure-starts-with-number-2)

```
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Stack Exchange}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[More text] A visual representation of these equations can be seen in figure \ref{fig:secfor}.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,axis lines = left,xlabel = x, ylabel = y,xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1,ymax=0,y dir = reverse,max space between ticks=1000pt,try min ticks = 3]
\addplot[domain=-1.2:-0.6,samples=7,-latex]{1.05*(cosh(x/1.05)-cosh(2.4/(2*1.05))};
\addplot[domain=-0.6:1.2,samples=10, dotted]{1.05*(cosh(x/1.05)-cosh(2.4/(2*1.05))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{fig 1 2 a} \label{sfig:secfora}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth,yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=top,axis y line=left,ylabel = y, xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,y dir = reverse]
\addplot[domain=-1.2:-0.6,samples=7]{0.34*sqrt(1+sinh(x/1.05)^2)};
\addplot[samples=7, domain=-1.2:-0.6, quiver={u={0},v={0.34*sqrt(1+sinh(x/1.05)^2)}},-latex](x,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{fig 1 2 b} \label{sfig:secforb}    \end{subfigure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\captionof{figure}{figure 1.2}  \label{fig:secfor}
\end{figure}
```

[more text] figure ref{fig:triangle}. [more text] figure \ref{sfig:secfora}[text] figure ref{sfig:trianglea}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}